# Add callback function to library

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I am using [color.js](https://github.com/PitPik/colorPicker/blob/master/colors.js), and I'm trying to add a callback function to `setColor`. I added the following code before [line #177](https://github.com/PitPik/colorPicker/blob/master/colors.js#L177):

```
if (_instance.options.setColorCallback) {
    _instance.options.setColorCallback(convertColors(type, save ? colors : undefined));
}
```

That works fine and well, but the problem is when I try using `setColor` using `Lab` color format. When I do that, the callback function doesn't execute. Here's how I `setColor` using `Lab` color space: ([Source](https://github.com/PitPik/colorPicker/issues/34#issuecomment-172960645))

```
if (type === 'Lab') {
    var factor = (e.clientX - startPoint.left) / currentTargetWidth;
    factor = factor > 1 ? 1 : factor < 0 ? 0 : factor;
    myColor.colors.Lab[mode] = (mode === 'L') ? factor * 100 : (factor * 255) - 128;
    myColor.setColor(null, 'Lab');
}
```

How can I add a callback function to `setColor`?

Comment: You mean you've added it *after* line 177 and before line 178?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's a bad practice to modify libraries like that, but if you have decided to do so then instead at line#177 do it at line#204, and replace

```
function convertColors(type, colorObj) {
```

with

```
function convertColors(type, colorObj) {

   var convertResult = __convertColors(type, colorObj);

   if (_instance.options.afterColorsConvert) {
       _instance.options.afterColorsConvert(convertResult);
   }

   return convertResult;
}

function __convertColors(type, colorObj) {
```

this is because setColor is wrapped at line#76 and in both code definitions of setColor, convertColors is used, so its better to extend convertColors functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I have 2 issues with that. 1 - Why is it bad practice to modify the library like that? 2 - If I do that the callback function will get called every time I convert the color. I want it to get called only when I `setColor`.

Comment: it's a bad practice because if a newer version of library is released then you cannot upgrade to it unless you do all the patches which you made in your existing version to the newer version.
Secondly, i looked in to the source code of colors.js, and saw that convertColors is inaccessible from outside the library, and only setColors uses this method internally.

Answer (score 0):

This question is obviously solved already, I just want to add some more information to it for completion ;o)

The function `setColor()` returns `convertColors()` wich does have a callback function called `convertCallback()` that you can use, so there is no need to create your own in `setColor()`.

Also, if you would add a callback before Line#177 that would be to early because `convertColors()` wouldn't have been called yet and therefore you would deal with wrong color values.

BTW: @Horay, I updated colorPicker with a demo (out commented) how to realize Lab sliders, if you're still interested.